# When we try to ZoomIn and ZoomOut on Xamarin Android, several color shades are occur Android version 7 and 8 only

Tags: xamarin.android, zooming, pinchzoom

[image]In cameraPageRenderer, we handle zoomIn and zoomOut in our application. When we try to ZoomIn and ZoomOut, several colour shades occur. Please take a look at this image. As a result, we are resolving this issue by handling PrepareAndStartCamera (). Please see the code snippet below.

public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{

```
        switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                oldDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                float newDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                if (newDist > oldDist)
                {
                    //mCamera is your Camera which used to take picture, it should already exit in your custom Camera
                    handleZoom(true, camera);
                }
                else if (newDist < oldDist)
                {
                    handleZoom(false, camera);
                }
                oldDist = newDist;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.PointerCount == 2)
        {
            float x = e.GetX(0) - e.GetX(1);
            float y = e.GetY(0) - e.GetY(1);
            return (float)Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    private void handleZoom(bool isZoomIn, global::Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        //camera.StopPreview();
        //  camera.Release();
        // camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
        global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.IsZoomSupported)
        {
            int maxZoom = parameters.MaxZoom;
            int zoom = parameters.Zoom;

            if (isZoomIn && zoom < maxZoom)
            {
                zoom++;
            }
            else if (zoom > 0)
            {
                zoom--;
            }
            parameters.Zoom = zoom;
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
           // PrepareAndStartCamera();
        }
        else
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "zoom not supported");
        }
    }
```

After using PrepareAndStartCamera(), when ZoomingIn or ZoomingOut the camera and taking a picture, it returns to the normal size picture. if we are not using this PrepareAndStartCamera() method, then the Color shades are appear.

```
private void PrepareAndStartCamera()
        {
            try
            {
                camera.StopPreview();

                var display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
                if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0)
                {
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                }

                if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270)
                {
                    camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
                }

                camera.StartPreview();
            }
```

}

Comment: seems that you have solved your problem by using PrepareAndStartCamera().

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT i calling PrepareAndStartCamera it goes initial state like without zoomin any suggestions for current state position

Comment: I use your code to test at Android 6.0, I can not encounter your problem, seems that someone have replied your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796802/using-pinch-to-zoomin-and-zoomout-some-unwanted-background-should-copied-color-a